# Search in Dolphin returns 'invalid protocol'

Tags: 17.10, search, dolphin

I set up a new ubuntu 17.10 and installed dolphin from Ubuntu software. When I do a search ('find'), after typing a few characters a message shows up 'invalid protocol'. 
Any packages missing to be installed?

Comment: I had this problem with KDE on 16.04. `Dolphin` needs the `Baloo` indexing package in order to do searches. Indexing can be turned off, but the package needs to be installed.

Comment: Baloo is installed. Must be some other reason.

Comment: I started Dolphin in terminal. Then performed a search which resulted in 'invalid protocol'. Here is the output of the terminal: Invalid Context= "stock" line for icon theme:  "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/stock/128/"
Trying to convert empty KLocalizedString to QString.
qt.accessibility.core: Cannot create accessible child interface for object:  PlacesView(0x5587b72b7330)  index:  23
kf5.kio.core: couldn't create slave: "klauncher said: Unknown protocol 'filenamesearch'.\n"

Answer (score 1):

You could try the instructions here:
https://www.ryananddebi.com/2015/07/13/linux-getting-find-working-in-dolphin-on-kde-linux-mint-and-kubuntu/

In short install  kde-baseapps, systemsettings and kfind. And DISABLE "Enable Desktop Search" in Systemsettings -> Desktop Search. It should work then. It did for me. Pretty counterintuitive but it works ;).